# Cause of iOS BLE packet loss, packet duplication

Tags: ios, bluetooth, duplicates, bluetooth-lowenergy, packet-loss

I built 3 different Apps using a single BLE device.
The device sends several values of several sensors to 2 Apps simultaneously.  Same packets to 2 Apps at the same time.
In Android Apps, they are fine.

But, in iOS devices, there are some packet loss and packet duplications.

The packet is 20 Bytes of size and transfered in 20 Hz, which is almost the limit of iOS BLE suggestion (as I know)

The detail of packet duplications.  I copied part of log. 
The App name is A and B for simplification.

## Same Packet came to both Apps.

2016-09-21 21:26:37.212 B

2016-09-21 21:26:37.267 A

## And the mode is changed. Some UI display changed.

## Duplication

In App A, 12 ea of Same packet came. (in 0.6 sec, interval of 0.002sec)

2016-09-21 21:26:37.269 A

Between 1st and 2nd packets, there is 0.5 sec delay and there is UI actions (display change, audio play)

2016-09-21 21:26:37.853 A

## During that time in App B, normal packets came.

So App A lost these packets.

2016-09-21 21:26:37.272 B

2016-09-21 21:26:37.722 B

2016-09-21 21:26:37.782 B   <= same packet which is duplicated in App A

In below article, there are problems when sending packets, but in my case there is no sending action.

[Core Bluetooth slow down when sending packets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19543673/core-bluetooth-slow-down-when-sending-packets)

Q1 > Is it a performance issue? I used iPad mini, which is same cpu with ipad 2. Quite old one.
Q2> Is there any possibility that this is caused by iOS bug?
Q3> Can performance issue cause this problem?